# Meteor CLI + Heroku -- Deploying with a Flag in the CLI

Tags: heroku, meteor

I'm testing an older package and it won't successfully run unless I boot Meteor with:

```
meteor --allow-incompatible-update
```

It's my intention to deploy this application to Heroku. I'm also using a buildpack to accomplish this: https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor

How does one deploy an app to Heroku while passing in a flag/setting on the CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fork the buildpack and edit this line: https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor/blob/master/bin/compile_meteor#L64

```
meteor build ../build --allow-incompatible-update --directory 2>&1 | indent
```

You can then use this fork as your buildpack.